# When is a module isomorphic to a dual of another module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, duality-theorems

For an $R$-module $M$, the dual is given by $M^*=Hom(M,R)$. I was wondering, can $M$ always be written in the form $M=N^*$ for some $R$-module $N$? If not, are there any known conditions for it?

I know that for some special cases, it is possible. For example, the reflexive modules. Also, since $(\bigoplus_i N_i)^*=\prod_i N_i^*$, this "class" of modules is closed under (possibly infinite) products (and limits in general).

The reason I want to know it is because if it is true for modules on rings, it is also true on quasi-coherent modules of schemes, and this would be a proof that all quasi-coherent modules are representable by schemes.

EDIT: It is indeed not true in general; and in cases when it is true, the morphism $ev: N\to N^{**}$ must have a left inverse (so in particular, it is injective). But that isn't a sufficient condition either, as the first commenter gave a counterexample.

Comment: If $|\Bbb N|<\nu<|\Bbb R|$ then a real vector space of dimension $\nu$ can't be a dual. :P

Comment: A necessary condition is that the module must be torsion free.

Comment: A vector space of denumerably infinite dimension over a field $K$ (for example  K[X]) is not a dual: see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54175/which-vector-spaces-are-duals). This is true independently of the continuum hypothesis ( in contrast to a comment above which requires its negation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For finitely generated modules over Noetherian integral domains, being the dual of another finitely generated module is equivalent to being reflexive; see e.g. Thm. 2.8 of [Karl Schwede's notes](https://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/Notes/GeneralizedDivisors.pdf).